1998-2010 movie about girl with monster mouth
Movie was around the '98-'10 era and was probably a B-movie.
The first scene showed the titular female character being dragged in a forest about to be killed, when a man steps in and kills the redneck who was about to shoot her. He takes the girl in and finds out she has a deformed mouth.
I can't remember most of the movie, but in the end, the man ends up taking her to the woods to kill her and ending up being shot, thus repeating a cycle.

Pretty sure I know what you're after, but do you remember anything else?  Was it in English? Where did you see it?

This reminds me of a scene in Jennifers Body with Megan Fox. But the rest of the description does not match.

@Walt, are you going to field this one?

@WillFeldman I was waiting for more details, but I guess they're not coming. You can answer it, if you want. Weird episode... Francisco was actually close! ;)

Jenifer, (2005), from the television series Masters of Horror.

Police officer Frank Spivey (Steven Weber) is eating lunch in his
  squad car when he happens upon a crazed man with a meat cleaver
  forcing a young woman (Carrie Fleming) onto the ground. When Spivey
  intervenes, the man tells Spivey that he "doesn't know what she is,"
  forcing Spivey to shoot the man before he kills her. As he begins to
  console her, he first notices that although she has an attractive
  body, her face is horrifically disfigured.

And at the end,

Grabbing her by the hair, he forces her through the woods to kill her.
  Just as he's about to strike her down, a deer hunter shoots and kills
  Frank. Frank's last words are "Jenifer," as the deer hunter moves to
  comfort her...just as Frank had done.

Here's a disturbing image.
